# Not able to get code for like button to put on website

Tags: facebook-like

When trying to get the code to put like button onto website it says "HREF is not recognized as valid URL".

I have a website that is run by a third-party. Is that a reason why I can not put the like button on that website?

Comment: Whats the URL you are trying?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the website URL you enter starts with http:// or https://
You can get the Like button code for any website online regardless of who maintains it.
Hope this helps. Cheers, Bobby